# How can I insert a good reads logo into an html page?

Tags: html

I'm a beginner, alright?
I'm trying to build an HTML page that needs social media logos. I have all the ones I need except for good reads.
https://www.goodreads.com/
I can't find how to build one in CSS. I've tried to copy the image, that doesn't work. Does anyone else know how to build a goodreads tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download a goodreads svg at [Goodreads](https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/306117/goodreads), open the file in your editor, copy the content and put it where you need it in your HTML file.

Comment: @SlipperyDuck777 thanks, I tried this, and I changed the a href to the goodreads page I want it to go to, but when I click on the logo it doesn't go to the page.

Comment: @slipperduck777 would you mind sharing these new updates?

Comment: @Kofi Amoussou, TYSM!! That worked, I used that for all of the icons and that also solved the link problem I had.

Comment: Glad it did help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

On goodreads.com, copy the image address and paste in into a new tab. If the new tab contains only the image, copy the image address again and paste it between the `src` tabs. Otherwise, keep copying the image address from the new pages.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you want to just put in the logo or make the logo a link to your goodreads account

For just the image you could use

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Put your metadata and link css here-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0KBL.png" alt="Goodreads">
  </body>
</html>
```

And for a social media link I recomend using a icons library like FontAwesome

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/393a279287.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fa fa-goodreads"><a href="goodreads.com/youraccount"></a></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyways good luck!